# For what reason(s) is it not desirable to have the amplifier gain depend on the β of the transistor.

Tags: amplifier, gain

For what reason(s) is it not desirable to have the amplifier gain depend on the β of the transistor.

Comment: I cannot yet add answers, so I will post a comment: A transistor's beta varies greatly, both as a production parameter, and as a result of various factors when in use. Temperature changes beta enough to be perceived when used as a n audio amplifier. Imagine you open the door of your car and your music becomes louder. Or you take some precision measurements, and find them corrupted by a change in room temperature. On the other hand, resistors with much better tolerance characteristics, are cheap and readily available. So they are used to obtain stable OPs.

Answer (score 6):

To ensure repeatability in production. Beta varies a great deal between examples of the same device, and units would have very different characteristics if they were not designed so that they were independent of parameters like transistor beta.

Comment: Even more significant than the fact that beta varies from one part to another is the fact that it varies depending upon a variety of conditions, including the nature of the signals being acted upon.  If one passes a sine wave through a transistor whose beta varies between 50 and 53 (about 6% variation) during each cycle, the wave will be very badly distorted.  If one designs a circuit that with infinite beta would have a gain of 10, then the effective gain would likely vary between roughly 8.333 and 8.412--about 1% variation.

Answer (score 4):

Take for example a [2N3904](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/2N/2N3904.pdf) npn transistor.  Min/Max beta is 100/300 for a given Ic.  That is 200 +/- 50% ! (that is, *fifty percent* variation from the mean).

On the other hand, you can cheaply get 1% resistors.

So the idea is to make the amplification depend more on those resistors than on the Beta.  The usual way to do it is to get a very high gain (Beta), which can vary a lot but it is still high, and use negative feedback to stabilize it to a smaller but more accurate and repeatable amplification value.

Answer (score 3):

This is a spin-off from the above answer. If you look at the open-loop characteristic of a simple op-amp it has massive DC gain that rapidly trails off from a few hertz until it becomes unity gain somewhere about 1MHz. It offers an impractical frequency response to most applications.

Controlling the gain with fixed resistors around the op-amp (or transistor to that matter) reduces the gain so that you get a "usable" flat bandwidth up to the point in the spectrum where beta is running out steam and as per the previous paragraph trails off to unity gain.

This is the benefit of using feedback resistors around a transistor or an op-amp - you get a more normal usable and easily predictable frequency response to the circuit you are designing.